# I sent 2.002 BTC using withdrawal tab in BITFOREX Exchange to Coinbase

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I withdrew 2.002 BTC from my BITFOREX account to my BTC Coinbase account over a week ago and when I look up the Transaction Hash it shows it is an unconfirmed transaction with 82 inputs ans only 2 outputs. How do I get my coins into my Coinbase account now??
Please help! Anyone!
Thanks!
PAC-Man

Comment: It doesn't say anything about exchanges and how to get the transaction pushed where it stopped and into rhe

Comment: And into the Coinbase account

Comment: If the answers to the linked "duplicate" question don't help you, you should contact Bitforex support directly.